# I want create a flickr gallery and when i click on image show pop up with the image and its tags, tittle, photo id

Tags: javascript, html, flickr

[Page´s photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XThy.png) Good morning, i am triying to create a flickr API with js and html, i search photos and shows it in a html, but i need when i click on a photo this appears in pop-up with it description, tags, tittle, photo-id.

That is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Creating your first app with Flickr API</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script>
function obtenerFotos(text) {
var apiurl;
apiurl = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=f0b84fba1c00631410b85b90720f52ba&text="+text+"&per_page=10&format=json&nojsoncallback=1";
$.getJSON(apiurl,function(json){
$.each(json.photos.photo,function(i,myresult){
var url = 'https://farm' + myresult.farm + ".staticflickr.com/" + myresult.server + '/' + myresult.id + '_' + myresult.secret + '_b.jpg';
$('<img/>').attr("src", url).appendTo("#results").wrap("<div class=\"slide\"><h3>"+ myresult.title + url +"</h3><a href='" + myresult.link + "'></a></div>");
                        $('img').click(function () { //al hacer click en una miniatura ampliamos la imagen
                            $('#imga').attr("src", $(this).attr('src'));

                            $('#fondo').fadeIn();
                        });
});
});
            $('#fondo').click(function () { //si clickeamos de nuevo volvemos a la pantalla principal
                $('#fondo').fadeOut();
            });

};

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="left_sidebar" class="container"></div>
            <input type="text" name="a" placeholder="Inserte su texto aqui" id="a">
              <button type="button" onclick="obtenerFotos(document.getElementById('a').value)">Buscar</button>


<div class="wraper" id="results"></div>
<div id="fondo">
<div><img src="" id="imga"/>

</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The part that show the photo is that:

```
                            $('img').click(function () { //al hacer click en una miniatura ampliamos la imagen
                            $('#imga').attr("src", $(this).attr('src'));

                            $('#fondo').fadeIn();
                        });
```

But doesn´t work dont show the photo in pop up and dont show description, title, id, tags.

Regards and thank you.

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: No, any error, i edit the post with a console image and the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code? i used [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp) to make it popup. Apply css according to your requirement.

```
   <html>

    <head>
        <title>Creating your first app with Flickr API</title>
        <style>
            #myImg {
                border-radius: 5px;
                cursor: pointer;
                transition: 0.3s;
            }

            #myImg:hover {
                opacity: 0.7;
            }
            /* The Modal (background) */

            .modal {
                display: none;
                /* Hidden by default */
                position: fixed;
                /* Stay in place */
                z-index: 1;
                /* Sit on top */
                padding-top: 100px;
                /* Location of the box */
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                /* Full width */
                height: 100%;
                /* Full height */
                overflow: auto;
                /* Enable scroll if needed */
                background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                /* Fallback color */
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
                /* Black w/ opacity */
            }
            /* Modal Content (image) */

            .modal-content {
                margin: auto;
                display: block;
                width: 80%;
                max-width: 700px;
            }
            /* Caption of Modal Image */

            #caption {
                margin: auto;
                display: block;
                width: 80%;
                max-width: 700px;
                text-align: center;
                color: #ccc;
                padding: 10px 0;
                height: 150px;
            }
            /* Add Animation */

            .modal-content,
            #caption {
                -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
                -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
                animation-name: zoom;
                animation-duration: 0.6s;
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
                from {
                    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
                }
                to {
                    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
                }
            }

            @keyframes zoom {
                from {
                    transform: scale(0)
                }
                to {
                    transform: scale(1)
                }
            }
            /* The Close Button */

            .close {
                position: absolute;
                top: 15px;
                right: 35px;
                color: #f1f1f1;
                font-size: 40px;
                font-weight: bold;
                transition: 0.3s;
            }

            .close:hover,
            .close:focus {
                color: #bbb;
                text-decoration: none;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */

            @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
                .modal-content {
                    width: 100%;
                }
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function obtenerFotos(text) {
                var apiurl;
                apiurl = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=f0b84fba1c00631410b85b90720f52ba&text=" + text + "&per_page=10&format=json&nojsoncallback=1";
                $.getJSON(apiurl, function (json) {
                    $.each(json.photos.photo, function (i, myresult) {
                        var url = 'https://farm' + myresult.farm + ".staticflickr.com/" + myresult.server + '/' + myresult.id + '_' + myresult.secret + '_b.jpg';


                        $('<img>').attr("src", url).width("400").attr("alt",myresult.title).appendTo("#imageList");

                        // Get the modal
                        var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

                        // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
                        //var img = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg');
                        var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
                        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

                        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

                        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                        span.onclick = function () {
                            modal.style.display = "none";
                        }

                        $("img").click(function () {
                            modal.style.display = "block";
                            modalImg.src = this.src;
                            captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
                        });
                    });
                });
            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="left_sidebar" class="container"></div>
        <input type="text" name="a" placeholder="Inserte su texto aqui" id="a">
        <button type="button" onclick="obtenerFotos(document.getElementById('a').value)">Buscar</button>

        <div id="imageList">
        </div>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
            <div id="caption"></div>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this work perfect, and if i want more in the description i can change myresult.title for a variable with tags etc no?

Comment: @Juan yes u can add more data into alt attribute. It will be displayed as description.